# Merge multiple excel to single worksheet with options

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2  sheets in one excel file, the first one is :

**Sheet: Person**

```
Code    date        start   end
2301    12/08/1993  08:02   08:17
4221    12/08/1993  09:04   09:25
2312    12/08/1993  10:02   10:28
1284    19/09/1994  11:02   11:21
2312    19/09/1994  15:57   16:20
1284    23/06/1995  17:12   17:35
2312    22/06/1996  13:14   13:32
4221    22/06/1996  15:53   16:13
4221    05/05/1999  08:06   08:22
2418    05/05/1999  08:10   08:33
2301    05/05/1999  09:12   09:37
2301    05/05/1999  09:28   10:28
2301    05/05/1999  13:28   13:38
```

Is a list of person of a company and anyone of them is identified by badge [row `Code`], what I hope is to Merge data by `code` to a costume sheet of a person, for example, for the person who have a number of badge 2301 he have his own sheet called B2301, so based on the first sheet "Person" I hope import data of a person like that grouped by `code` number of this person :

**sheet B2301**

```
 date       Period(min)
 12/08/1987 12
 ....       ...
```

So Period will be calculated from `start` and `end` rows.

I tried by using this formula but it's not working for me :

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$14,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$14=INT(RIGHT(CELL("filename",A1),LEN(CELL("filename",A1))-FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1)))),ROW(Sheet1!A$2:A$14)-ROW(Sheet1!A$2)+1),ROWS(Sheet1!A$2:A2))),"")`

Any Idea?

Comment: What is wrong with the formula?  What happens?  Also, if you are not looking for a VBA solution, I'd remove the excel-vba tag.  If you are looking for a VBA solution, I'd follow the advice of PKatona.

Answer (score 0):

This will require a lot of research on your part. You'll need to:

1. create a VBA Macro
2. define variables and create a loop to look at your main sheet.
3. create a sheet name based on the code.
4. check if the sheet already exists, if not, create it.
5. copy the values from the first sheet to the "code" sheet.
6. once all values are processed, go through each sheet, loop through your values and calculate your periods.

This is not a trivial amount of code. Do research on these 6 items and write the code. When you have that, display it and we can give you more direction.

Comment: Well it sounds like you want someone to write you code for you, which is not the intent of this website. The expectation here is that you have written some code and need further guidance.

I tell you what, I'll start you out. I'll check throughout the day. You show me your progress and I will help you along further.

1. On the Person excel workbook, click the "View" tab and then click the icon to the far right "Macros".
2. Type in "ProcessBadges" for the Macro name, and then click "Create".

Let me know when you've done that. I'll check back later.

Answer (score 0):

To populate the dates, in A2 put:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$14,MATCH(SMALL(IF(--MID(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),2,999) = Sheet1!$A$2:$A$14,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$14),ROW()-1),IF(--MID(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),2,999) = Sheet1!$A$2:$A$14,Sheet1!$B$2:$B$14),0)),"")
```

To populate the period put this in B2:

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(INDEX(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$14,MATCH(SMALL(IF(--MID(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),2,999) = Sheet1!$A$2:$A$14,IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$14=A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$14)),COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A2)),IF(--MID(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),2,999) = Sheet1!$A$2:$A$14,IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$14=A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$14)),0))-INDEX(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$14,MATCH(SMALL(IF(--MID(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),2,999) = Sheet1!$A$2:$A$14,IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$14=A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$14)),COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,A2)),IF(--MID(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),2,999) = Sheet1!$A$2:$A$14,IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$14=A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$14)),0)),"[m]"),"")
```

Both are array formulas and need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then Copy both down to desired rows.

[image]

Comment: It give me this error even I do a lot of modifications `we found a problem with this formula try clicking insert function `, maybe I enter something wrong, can you please try your example in real file please to be sure that works fine?

Comment: I did put it in a real file, hence the picture.  It works for me.  I did not photo shop the picture nor did I just put the numbers in.  the picture above is of my real file.